# Quarkus: The return value of "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.mapping.RuntimeResource.getProduces()" is null

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy, vert.x, reactive

I created Reactive SQL client on Quarkus using [this official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients), but while making GET request on http://localhost:8080/hello trying to query data from database, I get such an error:

```
2022-03-06 13:18:53,051 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) HTTP Request to /hello failed, error id: 2796a874-61d9-43ee-bd87-6f098cffa484-2: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.util.ServerMediaType.getSortedMediaTypes()" because the return value of "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.mapping.RuntimeResource.getProduces()" is null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.PublisherResponseHandler.handle(PublisherResponseHandler.java:203)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.PublisherResponseHandler.handle(PublisherResponseHandler.java:30)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:49)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:17)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:7)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:126)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.StaticHandlerImpl.lambda$sendStatic$1(StaticHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Hi, mind adding more information?

Comment: Hi! Uploaded project to Github: https://github.com/shgleb94/code-with-quarkus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
// Each element will be sent as JSON
@RestSseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

to your JAX-RS method.

However, you most likely also need to include `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson`.
Furthermore, you might want to revisit the use of `Multi` as a return type as you are likely looking for something like `Uni<List<Address>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I forgot to include quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson(